# How to access static child class properties in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, static

Take the following base case:

```
class Base1 {
  static options = {
    opt1: 1,
    opt2: 2
  }

  static func(option?: keyof typeof this.options) {
    console.log(this.options)
  }
}

Base1.func()
// Typescript accepts 'opt1', 'opt2', and undefined as parameters to the function
// { "opt1: 1", "opt2": 2 } is logged
```

I'm trying to expand this to work with inherited classes. For example (what I would like to see working):

```
class Base2 {
  static options = {}

  static func(option?: keyof typeof this.options) {
    console.log(this.options)
  }
}

class Sub2 extends Base2 {
  static options = {
    opt1: 1,
    opt2: 2
  }
}

Sub2.func()
// Typescript accepts unknown - SHOULD STILL ACCEPT opt1, opt2, undefined
// { "opt1: 1", "opt2": 2 } is logged
```

I've tried to get this working using generics but this won't even transpile anymore:

```
class Base3 {
  static options = {}

  // Parameter 'option' of public static method from exported class has or is using private name 'T'.
  static func<T extends Base3>(this: new () => T, option?: keyof T.options) {
    // Property 'options' does not exist on type 'new () => T'
    console.log(this.options)
  }
}

class Sub3 extends Base3 {
  static options = {
    opt1: 1,
    opt2: 2
  }
}

Sub3.func()
```

A couple questions:

1. How do you access the options property of the subclass for the typing of the option parameter?
2. If T extends Base3, why does options not exist on this? I've also tried `this: { new (): T } & T` as another attempt without different result

What am I misunderstanding about Typescript and how could I get this working?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible since static members cannot reference type parameters. You would have to use a workaround (IDK any of them, and cannot find any of them currently).

Comment: Nevermind, a workaround I remember is redefining the type: https://tsplay.dev/WvGlRw - does this work for you?